# Cannot get metamask account

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js, metamask

I used to get Metamask account address, but suddenly I couldn't get account and got this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No valid "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
```

I specified address like this

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })
```

The error happens in this code

```
createPlace(name) {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.state.placeList.methods.createPlace(name).send({ from: this.state.account })
    .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    })
  }
```

Are there any problem in my code?

Could you give me any advise, please?

Comment: Honestly, your code looks fine, I assume that you have some dummy mistake here, gl

Answer (score 0):

In that case the Metamask is nott able to connect to browser and inject web3 into it.

One solution can be 
You may have a line in your code which checks for the **CurrrentProvider** ?

Ex:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
}
```

change the line to

```
window.web3.currentProvider.enable()
```

and save the file while keeping the server running.

This should work for you.

Another thing you can do is to write your logic codes inside try block and do

```
window.web3.currentProvider.enable()
```